# How do I maintain persistent information over a multi-step input process?

Tags: 7, forms

I don't have a multi-step form. I have many forms that are presented over many steps depending on decisions made in previous forms and user role. How do I best store persistent information across all forms? Should I use some type of ctools cache, store the information in a cookie or should I attach the information as a query string to each URL request? I am currently using Rules and Rules link for this. Also, I intend to use hook_form_alter() to manage the information through the steps but I not sure how to securely maintain persistent information.

Answer (score 1):

Easiest is just save to $_SESSION which effectively stores it using the cookie for you. Are these anonymous users? Care may need to be taken if cookies are disabled in that case.

Comment: These are registered users. How do I get Rules to get or set the $_SESSION variable through a custom module or existing module?